# multiple application language in iTunes

Tags: ios4, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I develop a application and submit it on iTunes. and i also did localization for this application for German language. but in German market it showing Language : English. but i want to show both language English and German. like attach sample is showing :

[image: Sample image]

Thx
Mitesh

Answer (score 1):

see your localization string name change it to localizable.strings and then whatever your key put in your whatever language file.